# Help with rails rest standard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have a messages controller thats declared as a resource in my routes.

I want to be able to have a list view of received messages
and a different view of sent messages.

But I dont want to break the rest pattern... What do you guys reccomend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in *config/routes.rb*:

```
map.resources :messages, :collection => { :sent => :get, :received => :get }
```

Then in your *messages_controller.rb*:

```
def received
  @messages = Message.to(current_user)
end

def sent
  @messages = Message.from(current_user)
end
```

In your *message.rb* define these two named scope methods.

Or as Tony Fontenot pointed out:

```
def received
  @messages = current_user.messages.to
end

def sent
  @messages = current_user.messages.from
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do `@messages = current_user.messages.to` and `@messages = current_user.messages.from`

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple

`/messages?view=sent`

In your `index` method

```
def index
    @messages = case params[:view]
    when 'sent'
      Messages.sent
    when 'received'
      Messages.received
    else
      Messages.all
    end
end
```

See how the [`inherited_resources`](http://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) plugin handles Scoping.

Comment: Sent by whom? Received by whom? Not a complete answer imo. The Questioner also asked it to comply with RESTful practices. This does not. The model is also probably going to be called "Message".

Comment: Then NachoF will need to adjust the route to indicate the subject of the request.

`/client/73/messages?view=sent`

And replace Messages.[all|sent|received] with an appropriate finder.

possibly:
`client.messages.sent`

But in the question NachoF gave no information regarding Message associations.

Comment: And then he would use the params to call send on the messages association? What if I sent those params in as "delete_all"?